# Issue with pandas-profiling: Unknown Error during Data Preprocessing and Analysis

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-profiling

I've been working on data preprocessing and analysis tasks. To gain a comprehensive understanding of my data (data distribution and correlation analysis), I decided to utilize the **pandas-profiling** library. However, I've encountered an **unfamiliar error** during this process. For your reference, I've **attached an image depicting the error message**.

[image]

**Explored Solutions:**

It's worth mentioning that I'm executing my script within a Conda environment. In an effort to troubleshoot, I've experimented with different versions of Python, pandas, and pandas-profiling, but unfortunately, none of these efforts have successfully resolved the error.

**Current Package Versions:**

- Python: 3.10.12
- pandas: 2.0.3
- pandas-profiling: 2.9.0

If anyone within the community has any insights or suggestions regarding this error, I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: This looks relevant here: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Why resorting to posting an image here? Pretty low res, even. Hard to read.

Comment: Isn't pandas-profiling [deprecated](https://pypi.org/project/pandas-profiling/) in favor of 'ydata-profiling'?

Comment: I used ```ydata-profiling``` instead of pandas-profiling since ```pandas-profiling is deprecated```, and it turned out to work perfectly. I want to express my gratitude to @OCa for recommending the ```ydata-profiling```.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas-profiling is no more supported and does not support pandas2.. Try to use ydata-profiling https://pypi.org/project/ydata-profiling/.